# How to set a default value for an optional Range argument?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a function which would have a Range as an optional argument. Here's a minimal example of such function:

```
Function Example(s As String, Optional r As Range) As String
    Example = "Test"
End Function
```

This is ok and the VBA Module can be compiled. But I'm struggling to find out *how to set a default value* for this optional range argument, e.g. "B:B".

```
Function Example(s As String, Optional r As Range **= Range("B:B")**) As String
    Example = "Test"
End Function
```

This does not compile. It throws the error *"Constant expression required."*

Comment: Of course, I cannot use bold face in code, so the Function was defined as:Function Example(s As String, Optional r As Range **= Range("B:B")**) As String

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks, Scott showed me the way. I googled this further and the proper way seems to be something like this:

```
Function Example(s As String, Optional r As Range = Nothing) As String
    If IsMissing(r) Then
        r = Range("B:B")
    End If
    Example = "Test"
End Function
```

I can't fathom why you can define default values for pret

Comment: Good work finding `IsMissing`. Useful MSDN, [IsMissing Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/ismissing-function). Mentions limitations for `ParamArray` and simple data types (`Integer`, `String`, etc.).

Comment: Try `Optional r As Variant` if someone has problems. And in the function `set r = Range("B:B")`

Answer (score 6):

Check if the argument was passed inside the function and set it there if not.

```
Function Example(s As String, Optional r As Range) As String

    If r Is Nothing then Set r = Range("B:B")

    Example = "Test"

End Function
```

Comment: If your `Optional` is a `String` then it cannot be `Nothing` – type mismatch – so compare with an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Scott's answer is probably the way to go, but if you really want to be able to put a literal default value in the function header, you could change the argument type to `Variant` and assign a default `String` to it, converting this string to a range in the body of the function if need be:

```
Function Example(Optional R As Variant = "A:B") As String
    If TypeName(R) = "String" Then Set R = Range(R)
    Example = R.Address
End Function
```

Tested like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Range("A1:B1")

    Debug.Print Example()
    Debug.Print Example(R)
End Sub
```

Which prints:

```
$A:$B
$A$1:$B$1
```

In some contexts the flexibility of being to pass either a range or a string to the function could be useful. For example, you could pass the name of a named range directly to the function and have it work as expected.